# Parse Google Geocode JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, google-geocoder

I'm new to python and trying to parse a JSON from a Google Geocoding response with Python 2.7. The entire JSON file can be found here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60455118/data.json

Sample JSON:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "277",
               "short_name" : "277",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Bedford Avenue",
               "short_name" : "Bedford Ave",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "short_name" : "Williamsburg",
               "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "short_name" : "Brooklyn",
               "types" : [ "sublocality_level_1", "sublocality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Kings County",
               "short_name" : "Kings County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "11211",
               "short_name" : "11211",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "277 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.714232,
               "lng" : -73.9612889
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7155809802915,
                  "lng" : -73.9599399197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.7128830197085,
                  "lng" : -73.96263788029151
               }
            }
         },
```

I'd like the output to be in this format:

```
227, Bedford Avenue, Williamsburg, Brooklyn, Kings County, New York, United States, 11211, Latitude, Longitude
```

My script is as follows:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('c:\scripts\data.json') as f:
   data = json.load(f)


coordinates = data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]


for i in data["results"][0]["address_components"]:
   print i["long_name"]
```

It outputs in this format:

```
277
Bedford Avenu
Williamsburg
Brooklyn
Kings County
New York
United States
11211
```

How do I transpose this and add in the Lat Lon values?

Answer (score 3):

Put values in list and then `join` it using `","`

```
elements = []

coordinates = data["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]

for i in data["results"][0]["address_components"]:
   elements.append( i["long_name"] )

elements.append( str(coordinates['lat']) ) # convert to string to use `join`
elements.append( str(coordinates['lng']) ) # convert to string to use `join`

print ", ".join(elements)
```

-

```
277, Bedford Avenue, Williamsburg, Brooklyn, Kings County, New York, United States, 11211, 40.714232, -73.9612889
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what is your problem:

```
for result in data["results"]:
    address = address = {place['types'][0]: place ['long_name'] for place in data["address_components"]}
    address['lat'] = float(result["geometry"]["location"]['lat'])
    address['lng'] = float(result["geometry"]["location"]['lng'])
    print address
```